# How to make my bitbucket pipeline slack notify message into bold format

Tags: notifications, bitbucket, slack, slack-api, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to make the message bold so the person will notice the word

```
- step:
        name: Send Notification to Slack
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/slack-notify:2.0.0
            variables:
              WEBHOOK_URL: 'CLASSIFIED'
              MESSAGE: '<@1234>, There's an **ERROR**'
```

Answer (score 1):

These basic visual styles are very simple to use and can be formatted using a simple markup language called `mrkdwn`.

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#visual-styles

```
_italic_ will produce italicized text
*bold* will produce bold text
~strike~ will produce strikethrough text
```